# Jquery Conflict for back button code snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

upgraded from 1.4 to v=1.7

Here i am placing couple of request.

1. jquery snippet conflict
2. Back button snippet

> TypeError: $j(...).on is not a function

How popup alert when someone clicked the back button, below is the code but looks not working, still i have one more issue that is conflict, can you some one suggest the best way to resolve this issue.

```
  jQuery(function () {
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('', null, './');
        jQuery(window).on('popstate', function () {
            alert('Back button was pressed.');
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: working on jsfiddle.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh no bro

Comment: @Bharanikumar — If someone can't reproduce your problem, that's a good sign you need to add more detail to your test case until they can.

Comment: For anyone the above snippet working, please if jsfiddle url having in your hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for `on`:

> version added: 1.7

You must be using an older version of jQuery. Upgrade to a current version.

Comment: upgraded but still seeing conflict